# Create a mountable image with the newfs file system

Tags: linux, image, filesystems, mount, mount-point

I want to create a mountable image with the newfs file system which can be mounted with newfs file system. How can I do that?

I have tried to create an image with the command

```
dd if=localfiles.tar.gz of=/root/upload/test.img
```

but I could not creat a newfs file system. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=8M count=<depends on the size of the fs you need> of=/root/upload/test.img
$ mkfs.newfs /root/upload/test.img
# mount -o loop /root/upload/test.img /mnt
$ cd /mnt
$ tar xzf /path/to/localfiles.tar.gz
$ cd
# umount /mnt
```